# HTTPConnectionPool = 80 should be 8080

Tags: robotframework, urllib3

I'm trying to use ZapLibrary (https://github.com/airesv/robotframework-zaplibrary)
and when running my RobotFrameWork test it tries to connect to port=80

while in Zap my **localhost:8080** (so it is running on port 8080)

How can I change or set this to try to reach port 8080 instead

```
ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: http://zap/JSON/core/action/shutdown/?apikey=d9i7specimen (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000193028DF070>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Kan geen verbinding maken omdat de doelcomputer de verbinding actief heeft geweigerd')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1
goto
C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\urllib3

2

look in the files,
poolmanager,
connectionpool,
and ,connection

3
change 80 in 8080